# Why is the 'Declare before use' rule not required inside a class?

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I'm wondering why the declare-before-use rule of C++ doesn't hold inside a class.

Look at this example:

```
#ifdef BASE
struct Base {
#endif
    struct B;
    struct A {
        B *b;
        A(){ b->foo(); }
    };

    struct B {
        void foo() {}
    };
#ifdef BASE
};
#endif

int main( ) { return 0; }
```

If BASE is defined, the code is valid.

Within A's constructor I can use B::foo, which hasn't been declared yet.

Why does this work and, mostly, why only works **inside** a class?

Comment: This isn't a class just to let you know.

Comment: @thyrgle: Yes, it is.

Comment: @thyrgle: A `struct` and a `class` is the same except one default to `public` and the other `private`.

Comment: @thyrgle: struct isn't a class in C, but in C++, struct is just the same as class except with `public` as default access specifier

Comment: @Billy: It is? Wth? It's a struct, isn't a class like the evolution of the struct or something like that?

Comment: @thyrgle: See KennyTM's answer.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yep, something which doesn't make sense

Comment: @KennyTM, Lie: I think he meant something more like - In C, a `struct` doesn't embody the idea of a class.  In C++, a `struct` does embody the idea of a class.  It is the same as a `class` with `public` as the default access specifier.

Comment: Not that this answers your question completely, but if you separate the class implementation from its forward declarations, then declare-before-use holds.  This is commonly done with header and implementation file pairs (.h and .cpp).

Comment: That was mean to be C++ code. I used structs instead of classes just to avoid the needing of specifying public access...

Comment: @thyrgle, A struct is not "the same as a class except..." but it *is* a class. As is an union.

Comment: @NathanOliver Funny that you marked this question as duplicate of [SO: Do class functions/variables have to be declared before being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13094898/7478597). -- It's nearly two years older. However, I agree that the duplicate link is helpful.

Comment: @Scheff Age doesn't matter with duplicates.  I felt the newer Q and answers are better so I decide to close this as a dupe of the new one.  Feel free to cast a reopen vote if you want, or mod flag asking for merger instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because member functions are compiled only after the whole class definition has been parsed by the compiler, even when the function definition is written inline, whereas regular functions are compiled immediatedly after being read.  The C++ standard requires this behaviour.

Comment: That's also why you can't return instances of the class from inside the class definition (not references, but actual instances). The compiler can't tell yet how big your class is.

Comment: @Blindy: Huh? You can't? You *can* actually. You *can* return instances of the class from a member function declared in that class.

Comment: Hrm nevermind, I wonder what I was remembering then...

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering why C++ standard is like this. I guess DevSolar's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 9):

Well, to be pedantic there's no "declare before use rule" in C++. There are rules of *name lookup*, which are pretty complicated, but which can be (and often are) roughly simplified into the generic "declare before use rule" with a number of exceptions. (In a way, the situation is similar to "operator precedence and associativity" rules. While the language specification has no such concepts, we often use them in practice, even though they are not entirely accurate.)

This is actually one of those exceptions. Member function definitions in C++ are specifically and intentionally excluded from that "declare before use rule" in a sense that name lookup from the bodies of these members is performed as if they are defined *after* the class definition.

The language specification states that in 3.4.1/8 (and footnote 30), although it uses a different wording. It says that during the name lookup from the member function definition, the *entire* class definition is inspected, not just the portion *above* the member function definition. Footnote 30 additionally states though that the lookup rules are the same for functions defined inside the class definition or outside the class definition (which is pretty much what I said above).

Your example is a bit non-trivial. It raises the immediate question about member function definitions in *nested* classes: should they be interpreted as if they are defined after the definition of the most enclosing class? The answer is yes. 3.4.1/8 covers this situation as well.

"Design & Evolution of C++" book describes the reasoning behind these decisions.

Comment: For the standardese, see 9.2/2. The text at 3.4.1/8 is not sufficient. It just defines the scopes that are looked for for a name - if a name hasn't been declared yet in that scope, and there is no other rule (as such 9.2/2), it would be an error. This can be seen by trying to compile `struct A { void f(type); typedef int type; };` - 3.4.1/8 applies, but the code is not valid, because 9.2/2 does not apply.

Comment: Note that the rules for merely finding the name is also stated at `3.3.6/1b1`, but that rule is not sufficient - it would allow finding a name but it would not guarantee the parse state of its definition. For instance: `struct A { void f() { B a; } struct B { }; };`. This code is not valid if we only consider 3.3.6/1b1 without considering 9.2/2, because while we will find `B`, `B` will still be an incomplete class type. The rule at 9.2/2 will require the function body of `f` to consider `A` as if it already reached its closing brace, and will then find `B` as a complete class type.

Comment: However, I find it confusing that 3.4.1 uses the phrases "before its use ...". It seems it would be way clearer if it omitted those phrases and instead of saying "shall be declared in ..." it would say "is looked for in scope...". That way, names that are not in scope will not be found. Saying that "shall be declared in" is blabla, I think, and disrespects name hiding. 3.4.1/1 clearly says what happens: "In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed" - so why do those subparagraphs use such bloated wordings.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the chapter and verse of the standard on this.

But if you would apply the "declare before use" rule strictly within a class, you would not be able to declare member variables at the bottom of the class declaration either. You would have to declare them first, in order to use them e.g. in a constructor initialization list.

I could imagine the "declare before use" rule has been relaxed a bit within the class declaration to allow for "cleaner" overall layout.

Just guesswork, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

> The most stubborn problems in the definition of C++ relate to name lookup: *exactly* which uses of a name refer to which declarations? Here, I'll describe just one kind of lookup problem: the ones that relate to order dependencies between class member declarations. [...]
>
> Difficulties arise because of conflicts between goals:
>
> 1. We want to be able to do syntax analysis reading the source text once only.
> 2. Reordering the members of a class should not change the meaning of the class.
> 3. A member function body explicitly written inline should mean the same thing when written out of line.
> 4. Names from an outer scope should be usable from an inner scope (in the same way as they are in C).
> 5. The rules for name lookup should be independent of what a name refers to.
>
> If all of these hold, the language will be reasonably fast to parse, and users won't have to worry about these rules because the compiler will catch the ambiguous and near ambiguous cases. The current rules come very close to this ideal.
>
> [The Design And Evolution Of C++, section 6.3.1 called *Lookup Issues* on page 138]