# How c++ resolve name in this case?

Tags: c++

Following c++ code compiles using g++.  I'm a bit curious about how name a is resolve in the constructor

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
  A(int a) : a(a) { };
  const int a;
};

int main() {
  A a(10);
  printf("%d\n", a.a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: with help of `this` pointer

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094898/do-class-functions-variables-have-to-be-declared-before-being-used